# LNK2001 unresolved external symbols "class sample::Logger sample::gLogger" (?gLogger@sample@@3VLogger@1@A)

Tags: c++11

Hello I try to compile sampleonnxMNIST, I get these errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHNfb.png)

Does anyone know how I can resolve it?

Comment: Please don't show images of text. Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions. ALso please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: As for your problem, are you building with all source files? Linking with all libraries? Also see [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response